Cómo cambiar el color de un elemento del DOM cambiando el estilo en JS
Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código. Si quisiera que, los valores que están evaluados en la condición tomasen el color verde y los que no, el color rojo, ¿cómo podría realizarlo?
La verdad es que tengo la respuesta, pero he buscado de mil formas como se supone que debo dar con ella leyendo la documentación.
Esta sería la pregunta
<body>
    <ul id="datos"> </ul>
    <script>
        const datos = [1200, 350, 1500, 1400, 250, 5000, 1950, 1952]
        const d = document.querySelector("#datos")
        for (let valor of datos) {
            if (valor > 1000 && valor < 2000) {
                d.innerHTML += `<li>${valor}</li>`; 
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

y acá una posible respuesta.
    <script>
        const datos = [1200, 350, 1500, 1400, 250, 5000, 1950, 1952]
        const d = document.querySelector("#datos")
        for (let valor of datos) {
            const item = document.createElement(“li”)
            item.textContent = valor
            if (valor > 1000 && valor < 2000) {
                item.style.color = ‘green’;
            } else {
                item.style.color = ‘red’;
            }
            d.appendChild(item)
        }
    </script>

Como les digo, quisiera mejorar mi forma de buscar, porque leí varias preguntas y varias respuestas pero en ningún caso di con la respuesta que se nos propone.
De todas formas, entiendo la lógica del ejercicio y los métodos que utilizamos, pero no sabría como debería llegar a ese resultado sin haber visto "textContent" previamente.

Básicamente estas preguntando como saber algo antes de saberlo. Esa es la idea de estos ejercicios, que vayas aprendiendo y adquiriendo conocimientos, ahora que ya lo sabes en el próximo problema similar que tengas solo es recordar que ya pasas por lo mismo, a eso se le llama "experiencia"

color=(valor > 1000 && valor < 2000)?"green":"red"; d.innerHTML += `<li style="color:${color}">${valor}</li>`; / alt: color= ((valor-1000)*(valor-2000)<=0)?"green":"red";  o un if else

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo.
Tomando el código de tu primer ejemplo, puedes calcular el color usando el operador ternario e ir agregando el HTML de la misma manera, solo que ahora, indicando el color como parte del estilo.


const datos = [1200, 350, 1500, 1400, 250, 5000, 1950, 1952];
const d = document.querySelector("#datos");
for (let valor of datos) {
  let color = valor > 1000 && valor < 2000 ? 'green' : 'red';
  d.innerHTML += `<li style="color:${color}">${valor}</li>`; 
}
<ul id="datos"></ul>



Puedes lograr lo mismo usando un par de clases CSS y asignar la clase en lugar del valor:


const datos = [1200, 350, 1500, 1400, 250, 5000, 1950, 1952];
const d = document.querySelector("#datos");
for (let valor of datos) {
  let clase = valor > 1000 && valor < 2000 ? 'enrango' : 'fueraderango';
  d.innerHTML += `<li class="${clase}">${valor}</li>`; 
}
.enrango {
  color: green;
}

.fueraderango {
  color: red;
}
<ul id="datos"></ul>



Basándonos en el segundo ejemplo, no tienes por qué usar la propiedad textContent ni tienes por qué asignar antes el valor al elemento, puedes, por ejemplo, usar la propiedad innerText y asignarla al final, luego del color.


const datos = [1200, 350, 1500, 1400, 250, 5000, 1950, 1952];
const d = document.querySelector("#datos");
for (let valor of datos) {
  let item = document.createElement("li");
  if (valor > 1000 && valor < 2000) {
    item.style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    item.style.color = 'red';
  }
  item.innerText = valor;
  d.appendChild(item)
}
<ul id="datos"></ul>



En este formato también podrías usar una clase CSS y podrías usar el operador ternario para hacer el código más corto y legible.
También podrías valerte de la propiedad innerHTML para asignar el valor al elemento.


const datos = [1200, 350, 1500, 1400, 250, 5000, 1950, 1952];
const d = document.querySelector("#datos");
for (let valor of datos) {
  let item = document.createElement("li");
  item.className = (valor > 1000 && valor < 2000) ? 'enrango' : 'fueraderango';
  item.innerHTML = valor;
  d.appendChild(item)
}
.enrango {
  color: green;
}

.fueraderango {
  color: red;
}
<ul id="datos"></ul>



